# My computer won’t exit the “preparing automatic repair”

Tags: windows-10, bios

So the other day (July 24 my birthday) I wanted to give my brother my second monitor as I’ve had no use for it and I felt generous. While in the process of that I turned off my computer and unplugged my second monitor (a small 22” acer) and once I turned my computer back on all I saw was the Asrock logo and a spinning circle (like a loading one) and so I thought it was just taking its time so I went to dinner and came home roughly 3 hours later and it was still loading so I looked on other forms. All of them didn’t work, I can enter bios and so I tried resetting bios and it didn’t work. Now I sit here 3 days after dumbfounded on what to do, I’ve cleaned my pc. I’ve also plugged back in that second monitor thinking it would change something also didn’t work. Now I figured you’d want my specs, amd fx-8320, a 1030, one stick of ram, and a 970M pro 3 asrock motherboard, and I’m running windows 10.

Comment: Start with a bootable USB key and see if the disk drive can be accessed and read properly. Disk drive error seems likely in this situation.

Comment: So I tried that, but once I loaded it up it showing the error message, “your PC/Device needs to be repaired” then “File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe” then “Error code: 0xc000000e” then “You’ll need to use a recovery tools. If you don’t have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer” then there are two options “Press enter to try again” and Press F8 for startup setting” but I can’t do any of them it doesn’t leave the page I’m currently on. My computer Is old and junk but i don’t have the money for a new one so please help!!

Comment: It appears your drive has failed and needs to be replaced.